# How to view a city's already completed City Improvements in Endless Legend?

Tags: endless-legend

When clicking on a city we have available a plethora of information on it: available constructions, a construction queue, governor and garrison info, city's happiness, production and so forth. But how to check **what had already been constructed**?

Answer (score 1):

Let me answer this question by citing [this answer](https://steamcommunity.com/app/289130/discussions/0/45350245315153973/#c45350245472235701) from the game's `Steam Community` board:

> I found it, there is a "Browse" button up top on the City Info Screen.
>   It shows you everything that is built. Can't believe i overlooked it.

and a little visual cue:

[image]